# Symfony 4 with translations, no route to / without _locale

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-4.4

I created a Symfony 4.4.8 project with translations to English and French languages, so I followed the steps:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

and set:

**config/packages/translation.yaml**

```yaml
framework:
    default_locale: 'fr'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks: ['en', 'fr']
```

**config/routes/annotations.yaml**

```yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: fr|en
```

and a **src/Controller/HomeController.php** with

```php
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    private $session;
    
    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index() {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
        
    }
```

I have the translation files in *translations* folder and when I run *localhost:8000/fr* or *localhost:8000/en*, it works fine, my *home/index.html.twig* is shown.

The issue is when I run **localhost:8000/**, it shows me the default *Welcome to Symfony* page with "You're seeing this page because you haven't configured any homepage URL."

Is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204512/redirect-all-routes-without-locale-to-new-routes-including-locale-in-symfony-2) for sf2 will work on sf4?
Is anybody know how to solve it ?

I tested also to change the route in HomeController to:
`@Route("/{_locale}", name="home", defaults={"_locale"="fr"}`
but it returns exception:
`Route pattern "/{_locale}/{_locale}" cannot reference variable name "_locale" more than once.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround, added:
`RedirectMatch ^/$ /fr`
in my virtualhost (with apache2 server)

pure symfony solution shoud be better !

Answer (score 0):

I would guess a bad routing configuration. I couldn't recall a default behaviour where we can set the locale by adding the locale code in the URL so I would guess it is something your added ;)

Symfony resolves the route in the same order as you declare the route. So one solution would be to import 2 times the same route but with the prefix:

```yaml
# config/route.yaml
app_front:
    type: annotation
    resource: '../src/Controller/*.php'
    prefix: /
    options:
        expose: true

app_localized_front:
    type: annotation
    resource: '../src/Controller/*.php'
    name_prefix: localized_
    prefix: /{locale}
    options:
        expose: true
```

I know the previous config works, but I don't know if this is the more elegant way to do it :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, with it, *localhost:8000* shows the right page… but after if I switch to another page, it works, always without _locale and if I click on my **en** menu to switch in english, it stays in french, just adding **?_locale=en** at end of url

Comment: So you may have to remove the `app_localized_front` and add an event listener that looks the `_locale` query from the request and switches the locale ;)